# How can I optimize javascript assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I've already finished my project, and it seems working fine.

But, I've just found that there's more things to do with optimization.

Google's PageSpeed Insight just told me that
I have to `Remove Render-Blocking JavaScripts`, `Optimize CSS Delivery` and `Leverage Browser Caching`

About `Remove Render-Blocking JavaScripts`, and `Leverage Browser Caching`, it says that I have to work with my Assets Javascripts.

They are currently stated just like this in view

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'illuminate.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrapSwitch.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'bootstrap.js.coffee' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails.js' %>
```

and its html ouput is this

```
<script src="/assets/application-21cb698a1b325807d74e3f5588e.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/illuminate-1a2b0535b4a3f7468aec74882e25f3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrapSwitch-ae37e5eb28f943501b59b08ac6234.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-1b52926900736585a26c3fe0975f73.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-e46b066113d4a1ff96120b8493021d9.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I change this to change this in order to archive?

and about `Optimize CSS Delivery`, it says that I have to optimize these

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'bootstrapSwitch' %>
```

and this is its html ouput

```
<link href="/assets/application-e8a61afef574ba15cb71a3730d2b6b8e.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrapSwitch-b3ea2e51b3529f79637f5a8a9ef54712.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

How can I modify all of these?

Comment: Any reason why you're listing your assets in the HTML instead of concatenating them through the asset pipeline?

Comment: @depa Sorry this is the only way I know. That's the only reason why. Am I supposed to concatenate all js files together into on js?

Comment: I really think you should go through this. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Or this. http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: @depa Thanks! So do you think those would solve my problem that I'm facing?

Comment: That, plus moving the javascript include line to the bottom of your `</body>` tag.

Comment: @depa javascript always should go to the end part of codes???

Comment: @MKK, yes, that helps your page render faster.

Comment: @depa  and how can I set up caching for javascript assets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

1) [minifying](https://javascript-minifier.com/) your javascripts : smaller the size, the faster will your pages load

2) using a CDN to host your assets : this helps to load your assets faster and hence a better response time

3) @depa gave some nice pointers to asset pipelines in rails, check that out as well

and you'll be good.

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I know what to do now:)

Comment: MKK, try using google closure compiler to minify js. It does a lot more than just minify. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/